# Why can linux not see usb devices present on startup?

Tags: wifi, usb, keyboard, startup, mouse

I am trying to run linux (tails, which is based on debian) on a laptop (Lenovo 11.6 Inch Ideapad 100s) from a live usb drive. However, once I get past the boot menu, the mouse and keyboard stop working. An external mouse & keyboard on the second usb port work, however. When I look in dmesg, I see something about the usb failing to peer. Additionally, I can not find any evidence of any kind of wireless card - despite the fact that it effortlessly connects to wifi when booted in windows.

On close inspection, I have concluded that internally, the built-in mouse, keyboard, and wireless card are all connected via usb, and that for whatever reason any usb devices attached when the laptop starts, become inaccessible.

Why is it that windows can recognize these devices perfectly fine, but linux cannot? What makes the externally attached devices work? Is there any way to fix this? Particularly the wifi, as there is no other way to connect to the internet.